# Is it correct to put an “a” or "another" before the word "dimensions"?

Tags: word-meaning, articles, singular

I've noticed many people say something like

> *they live in another dimensions*...,

and

> *in a dimensions of*...,

but I am wondering if it's correct to put an “a” or "another" before the word "dimensions".
Can the plural form of "dimensions" in some certain cases be regarded as a singular?

BTW, what's the exact meaning of "dimensions" in such a sentence like "they live in another dimensions"?

Comment: Where on earth have you seen this? It is quite unacceptable.

Comment: No, this isn't a possible use...not sure where you could have seen this.

Comment: You could say that they live in other dimensions, or the phrase "in a dimension", but neither *another* nor *a* pairs with dimension**s** properly.

Comment: @StoneyB I watch a TV town hall meeting program(Hannity? I don't quite sure the program's name)，and I bet I heard a guest said “live in another dimensions”.

Comment: @dennylv - Sometimes people speak imprecisely or incorrectly, especially when they're trying to think of what they're going to say while they're saying it.  StoneyB, Alex K, and Jason Patterson are entirely correct.  It should be *a dimension*, *another dimension*, or *other dimensions*, but *another dimensions* is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular should be used:

> They live in **another dimension**

or possibly

> They live in **other dimensions**

We live in a four dimensional universe: up/down, left/right, forward/backward, and time, that is our reality (as we know it today). If someone is living in **another dimension**, it means they are living in a different reality to ours.

The phrase:

> ...*with*in *the* **dimensions** of

Could possibly be used to introduce a frame of reference:

> ..**within the dimensions of** Klingon society, it is possible to...

Answer (score 0):

For starters, **A** and **An** have rules.

> **A** = the following word starts with a consonant.
>
> There is **a** green dot on my orange.
>
> **An** = following word starts with a vowel.
>
> There is **an** orange speck on my apple.

So it would never be *an dimension* but the indefinite article **a** dimension.

Now, moving on to your questions: You would never couple *dimension* with **an** because of the above. But *another*, *parallel* and *unknown*, etc. would be just fine.

Meaning of Dimension in this context: A completely different reality, operating in its own timeline. Or, a being who operates outside of our four dimensions (length, width, height, time).

Comment: I am very sorry that I made a terrible mistake. It's not an "an", but a "a". I've   edited my post.